# C++17: Keep only some members when tuple unpacking

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17

Let's imagine you need to call the following method:

```
std::tuple<int, int, int> foo();
```

In C++17, you can call the function and unpack the tuple in a single line:

```
auto [a, b, c] = foo();
```

Now, how can I proceed to store only `b` and `c` and to discard `a`?

Currently, I'm only aware of two options:

---

1 - I can use a dummy variable when auto-unpacking

However, the dummy variable will be unused and it will issue a warning, so if I want to silent that warning the code will be quite unpleasant to see:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable:4101)
// ReSharper disable once CppDeclaratorNeverUsed
auto [_, b, c] = foo();
#pragma warning(pop)
```

---

2 - I can store the whole tuple and use `std::get` to retrieve the reference to the only variables I need. The code is less unpleasant but the syntax is also less straightforward.

Moreover, this code's size increases by one line for each new value that we want keep in the tuple.

```
auto tuple = foo();
int b = std::get<1>(tuple);
int c = std::get<2>(tuple);
```

---

*Is there another and more straightforward method to unpack only some parameters in a tuple?*

Comment: If the warning is your main concern, I suppose you could try silencing it with `[[maybe_unused]]`.

Comment: The title asks about keeping one element while the body of the question asks about keeping 2.

Comment: @BaummitAugen well, Visual Studio seems to not care and to issue the warning at compile time anyway.

Comment: This is explicitly talked about in [the original proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0144r0.pdf) in section 3.7. And the "silence warnings" is explicitly mentioned as not enough of a use-case.

Comment: @Lovy Looks like that doesn't apply anyway, according to the answer. That was just a guess on my part.

Comment: If you don't care about default-initializing your variable, you could use `std::tie` with `std::ignore`.

Comment: I know that clang doesn't issue a warning if you use at least one of the bindings. Issuing warnings that the language doesn't have a fix for is not really great IMO

Comment: @Lovy Note that ReSharper C++ does support `[[maybe_unused]]` applied to a structured binding declaration, as do clang and GCC. Clang and GCC also suppress the "not used" warning if at least one of the structured bindings in the entire declaration used - I'll implement the same logic in ReSharper C++ ([RSCPP-22313](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-22313)). It seems to me that MSVC should support both of these mechanisms, probably worth filing a request with them.

Comment: @Lovy Actually [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/113023/maybe-unused-with-structured-binding-still-causes.html) is the requst about `[[maybe_unused]]` support. Looks like it has been implemented in VS 15.7.

Answer (score 58):

Another alternative is to use an `std::tie`:

```
int b, c;
std::tie(std::ignore, b, c) = foo();
```

**Edit**

As mentioned in the comments, there are some issues with this approach:

- No type inference possible
- The objects must be constructed before, so unless the default constructors are trivial, it's not a good alternative.

Comment: This is quite convenient, however it is impossible to use type inference with this method, which is still an important drawback.

Comment: Another drawback is that you need some default-constructed instances of the objects, which might not always be possible or optimal.

Comment: Yes, it is only convenient in a few cases

Answer (score 50):

Unfortunately [*structured bindings*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) do not explicitly support discarding members, and attributes such as [`[[maybe_unused]]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) cannot be applied to *structured bindings* (there's a proposal for that: [**P0609**: "Attributes for Structured Bindings"](https://wg21.link/P0609)).

Here's a possible solution:

```
auto [a, b, c] = foo();
(void) a; // unused
```

Comment: BTW, what's the correct terminology for the identifiers inside the structured bindings declaration? E.g. what should I call `a` in the example above? A "binding"?

Comment: I don't think there's a specific name. Identifiers, or "names of structured bindings" is what the standard calls them?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo it's *[name of an lvalue](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind)*.

Answer (score 24):

You could write a helper function that only gives you back certain indices of a `std::tuple`:

```
template <size_t... Is, typename Tuple>
auto take_only(Tuple&& tuple) {
    using T = std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>;

    return std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<Is, T>...>(
        std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))...);
}

auto [b, c] = take_only<1, 2>(foo());
```

Or drops the head or something:

```
template <size_t... Is, typename Tuple>
auto drop_head_impl(Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<0, Is...> ) {
    return take_only<Is...>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
}

template <typename Tuple>
auto drop_head(Tuple&& tuple) {
    return drop_head_impl(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple),
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<Tuple>>>());
}

auto [b, c] = drop_head(foo());
```

But the above implementations almost certainly have some lifetime complexity issues that directly using structured bindings won't - since there isn't any lifetime extension here.

So just, do what [Vittorio says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50176479/2069064):

```
auto [a, b, c] = foo();
(void)a;
```

Comment: Returning a combination of the incoming tuple and a tie of the elements you want would emulate lifetime extension pretty well.

Answer (score 7):

MSVC has already [fixed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/209177/view.html) this in VS 15.7 Preview. The final 15.7 release should be available in the coming weeks. This means that the current logic supported by the latest releases of all major compilers is as follows:

- If at least one of the structured bindings in a structured binding declaration is used, no "Unused variable" warning will be issued for other bindings in the same declaration.
- If none of the bindings in a structured binding declaration are used, it is possible to silence the warning by using the `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute:

  ```
  [[maybe_unused]] auto [a, b, c] = foo();
  ```

Comment: @Alexander Note that in practice you'd probably never need the second construct. If you don't use any of the bindings, why do you have the structured binding declaration in the first place?

Comment: Oh I missed that. "If *none* of the bindings"

Comment: @igorakhmetov RAII types are declared but never used ;) (I'm not sure if a function returning multiple RAII types is a good idea)

Comment: I do not believe the first bullet is correct. At least in this context: `for ([[maybe_unused]] auto [hash, state] : uniqueStates)`. `hash` is definitely unused but even with `[[maybe_unsed]]` I still get an unused variable warning with both GCC and MSVC.

Comment: I take the other approach: I disable `unused variable` warnings since one of the compiler's core jobs is to optimize that sort of thing for me. The more it does for me, the more I get done, the more value I bring.

Comment: @jstine I believe that warning is not there for optimization concerns. Think about the case you refactored a code and there are unused variables left. It is well possible that you missed something in that case, or at least they are confusing artifacts now.